# Want to integrate auth0 in ionic using capacitor

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, auth0, capacitor

I want to integrate auth0 in my ionic4 application. I think I am supposed to have separate implementation of auth0 for web(pwa) and android/ios. I am using capacitor and I am not able to find an appropriate solution. Is there any way in which I can maintain a single code base for all platforms?

Comment: Hello. Ionic is cross-plaftorm framework. It mean you can Build apps in one codebase, for any platform. You don't need to separate code for different platform. With auth what did you mean? you want to implement auth control by router navigation or you want to create login flow with api or local storage?

Comment: Do you use React, Angular or web components? Auth0 site has some tutorials on this question; but, as for me, they're outdated a bit. Playing around setting up Auth0 for React app, based on Capacitor. This ionic doc page looks useful for me: https://ionicframework.com/docs/enterprise/auth-connect

Comment: @B.Bohdan  Yes there is this enterprise plugin available, which was expensive for my project. I tried to find another way but after a lot of research, I ended up maintaining two separate implementations of auth0 for web and mobile.

Comment: I decided to use Auth0 API to handle auth on mobile app. Looks OK. I also explored ability just to add deeplinks for standard Auth0 approach, but it also requires fees fr developer accounts.

Comment: @Divya Can you describe your solution in answer to this question, please? Think, that it will be helpful for lots of developers faced similar problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to use Auth0 API to handle appropriate actions: Sign Up, Sign In, Sign Out and Renew Token. You can find detailed description for lots of actions at [Auth0 docs](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication).

So, I managed to create utility functions like the following one:

```js
import environment from 'environment';

import * as constants from './constants';

const signUp = async (email: string, password: string): Promise<any> => {
  const resonse = await fetch(constants.AUTH0_ENDPOINTS.SIGN_UP, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      client_id: environment.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
      connection: constants.AUTH0_DATABASE_NAME,
      email,
      password,
    }),
  });

  return resonse.json();
};

export default signUp;
```

Also I implemented `Auth` class that is responsible for session operating, refreshing token and silent auth.